# SQLException: No suitable driver in Jboss Fuse

Tags: oracle, jbossfuse

I am using c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource to connect to my oracle database and here is the code snippet and i have deployed this application in Jboss Fuse ESB

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:xe" />
    <property name="user" value="test" />
    <property name="password" value="test" />
 </bean
```

when i try to insert values into the database am getting 
 **com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@339d05df -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278)[:1.7.0_55]**

when I use org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource instead of ComboPooledDataSource it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I've previously had issues setting up connection pools in Fuse/OSGi because the connection pool bundle (in this case the bundle containing com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource) doesn't include the driver it's using in its Import-Package. Could this be the problem?

If so, there are a number of options to resolve the problem. For example, you could, e.g.:

- repackage the pool to include the Import-Package
- make the JDBC driver a fragment bundle of the pool bundle

You'll find that searching for 'OSGI JDBC pool' normally fires up lots of additional articles and hints around this problem.